# One row of the for loop being inserted

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, for-loop

I have the following for loop that gives me: `Cat: 1, Sort: 20 Cat: 2, Sort: 13`

Do I need to do a count onto the `$cat` and `$sort` in my data I am pushing into my query? as I am only getting the second row in my database instead of both values:

**For Loop:**

```
        for($i = 0; $i < count($categories); $i++)
        {
            $cat  = $categories[$i];
            $sort = $sortOrder[$i];

            print("Cat: $cat, Sort: $sort \n");
        }
```

**Insert Query:**

```
$this->Ps_products_model->brand_by_category_insert($brand_name,$brand_id,$cat,$sort,$state);
```

Comment: Are you executing the insert call in the for loop?

Comment: Maybe check how you get those values from mysql,some methods Ex:fetchColumn - increment the counter and you skip one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your print() call with your insert query.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($categories); $i++)
{
    $cat  = $categories[$i];
    $sort = $sortOrder[$i];

    $this->Ps_products_model->brand_by_category_insert($brand_name,$brand_id,$cat,$sort,$state);
}
```

Comment: Well, glad you are getting close to resolution. I know you've been at it a while. Had to drive home and couldn't finish the answer to your original question.